# Time complexity for inner loop

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

What's the time complexity for this code?

```
for (int i = 1 to n) {
  for (int j = i to n) {
    for (int k = j to n) {
      Sum += a[i]*b[j]*c[k]
    }
    If (gcd(i,j) == 1) {
      j = n
    }
  }
}
```

The first loop is n.
The second loop is n - i
And the third one is n - j.

I and J are the same. So the interesting is in the second and third loops.  The gcd is going to work everytime i and j are different. So J is going to really work only like "once" per loop, so we can say j loop is constant. And K is going to be like (n-j) times, so (n - j) * n = n^2. So my guess is that the time complexity is O(n^2).

What do you think?

Comment: Your thinking seems to be right, but your wording of it looks insufferably sloppy to me -- in particular you keep abusing the word "is" to mean things it really can't support. Don't say that a loop "is $n-j$" when you mean that the loop "executes $n-j$ iterations", and don't say "is constant" for "executes a constant number of iterations".

Comment: Also (in comment to my confusion which led to my wrong -- now deleted -- answer): who did write this? This code is horrendously confusing: if the goal is to have the value that $j$ takes be only $i$, why add an inner "for" loop with a further test that changes the variable's value (not very clean practice)? This looks like obfuscation more than good practice.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections Henning. I'll try to be more careful with my wording.

Comment: @ClementC. It's a code for analysis of loop's time complexity. It's made on purpose to be confusing. It only has academical use.

Comment: Also, another point: you cannot really assume the test for the GCD is unit cost (as say $i\neq j$ would be...), but instead is something like $\log i$. So the fincal complexity would actually, because of that additional loop+check, slightly more than quadratic: $\Theta(n^2\log n)$.

Comment: The `j=n` would be a stinker in production code, except perhaps if you're writing in an extremely restricted language that doesn't provide a more explicit way to break out a loop. In _pseudocode_ it is a complete and total abomination that should never be written down in that way.

Comment: @ClementC.: Fortunately the `gcd` is outside the innermost loop so it's only executed $O(n)$ times, and its complexity is drowned out by the work spent in the inner loop.

Comment: @ClementC.: And actually, computing the GCD of $(i,i)$ or $(i,i+1)$ -- which are the only instances actually being called here -- only takes one or two rounds through Euclid's algorithm, and doesn't get near the logarithmic worst case.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I see, thanks :) (As a first thing to look at in the morning, this is both making me very confused and prone to errors, and also a bit sad.) Sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time complexity of the innermost loop is proportional to $n-j+1$.

Then, assuming that the assignment $j:=i$ indeed causes a loop exit, the intermediate loop executes at most twice every time it is entered, for $j = i$, and possibly $j=i+1$.

So the total cost is proportional to $(n+n-1)+(n-1+n-2)+\cdots (2+1)+1=n^2$.

Comment: @ClementC was right to worry about the cost of GCD computation. Quite logically, only a constant number of Euclidean iterations will be performed per invocation. Unless the GCD algorithm used is subtraction- rather than division-based, and will require like $i+1$ subtractions when $j=i+1$. Fortunately, this doesn't increase the asymptotic complexity.